# How to get arguments of Main method in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In C# Console Application, Main method has a string() argument, but in VB.NET, the Main method doesn't contain the argument, if I set command line arguments, how to retrieve them?

In C#, if I right click the project and select Properties, set command line arguments in debug item, I can use args[0], args[1] and so on to achive my arguments. In VB.NET, I found

```
System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

can also achive them, but it contains one more argument, it also contains the path of the process, anyone can help?

Comment: What's the problem? Just ignore the extra parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could add them to the entry point method signature (`ByVal args() As String`) and access them just as you would in C#. You could also use VB.NETs `My` class to access them such as `My.Application.CommandLineArgs`.

Answer (score 9):

You can just add the arguments to the `Main` methoid, and it works just like in C#:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
```

Answer (score 3):

and then you can use this code snippet to actually make use of the command-line arguments.  Not asked or needed by the original poster but provided for those who run across this post.  This snippet shows how to see if there are command-line arguments and how to access them:

```
Dim myFilename As String
If args.Length > 0 Then
        myFilename = args(0)
End If
...
```