# vb.net creating an application that can be called by arguments

Tags: vb.net, windows, arguments

I'm creating a AddIn application for Autodesk Inventor. This AddIn has the purpose to have some designtools that will increase the productivity.

(This tool in particular will perform a copy design but that just for info.)

I have written the tool in a standalone application and it worked, then I added into the Autodesk Inventor AddIn and it didn't work anymore.

So I searched around a bit and I found that I should keep the standalone application and call it from the AddIn.

This would be the call from my AddIn
I'm doing it like this I think, there are a bunch of methods on the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page but, I guess this is what I need

```
Sub OpenWithArguments()
    ' url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
    ' by passing them as arguments.
     Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com")

    ' Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.htm")
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\myPath\myFile.asp")
End Sub 'OpenWithArguments
```

But how do I create my copydesign.exe that it can accept arguments when I call it?

Comment: I suggest you read this question (how to get arguments of Main method) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779446/how-to-get-arguments-of-main-method-in-vb-net

Comment: Yea.. but I don't quite know how to implement it, as this is the first time ever I try to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two options (that I know of) :

**Option 1**

*Use the Main method with argument.*

Somewhere in you code there is your main method, i.e. the first method that will be called when your application starts. It should look like this :

```
Sub Main()
  ...
End Sub
```

You can actually decide that this method should receive arguments :

```
Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
  For Each Arg As String in cmdArgs
    'Do some stuff with this Arg
    Debug.Writeline("Argument : " & Arg)
  Next For
End Sub
```

[Check this link for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx)

**Option 2**

*Use the CommanLine property of Environment*

```
Sub Main()      
  Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
  For Each Arg As String in arguments
    'Do some stuff with this Arg
    Debug.Writeline("Argument : " & Arg)
  Next For
End Sub
```

[Check this link for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Be aware that usually the first argument you receive will be the path to your executable... So you always have one more argument than needed...

Comment: Ok, I have tried it. And I can pass arguments to the application using option 2. Just one problem. I have 2 paths that need to be passed as argument and my accepting application reads more than 2 arguments. there are spaces in the path argument which causes this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the input arguments in your application by using `System.Envirement.CommandLine` and do appropriate action for each command. but I recommend choose another communication approach.

Comment: As I stated before, this is the first time ever I try to do this. Could you please specify other communication approaches that can be used?

Comment: It depends to your situation, how many communication is needed. can you use Dll libraries instead of two .Exe file? maybe Pipes, shared memory, sockets, Remoting, WCF and ...

Comment: The communication is simple, 4 arguments are required to run the copydesign method, no feedback is required when it's done. All arguments can be string as its all filenaming. My add-in is a .dll library and my copy tool is a .exe don't know if it can be a .dll and how it would work. Only created a .dll file from a template provided by autodesk inventor.